# PHP how to access to config file from many php files?

Tags: php, file

In php how can I make this more elegant:

I have a config file from which I need values in different php files. So I add `$config_ini = parse_ini_file($ini_path, TRUE);` to every of my php files.

I think is better to define the ini path in one variable which is available over all of my files. Next step would be to make the variable which contains the ini file's content available to all other files.

Is this the correct/ best way? 
How to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) using `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is include a file in every page that does the parse_ini_file call.

File1.php: `$config_ini = parse_ini_file($ini_path, TRUE);`

(All Other Files That Need Those Variables): `require_once 'PATH/File1.php'`

`echo $config_ini['mykey'];`

Instead of

(All Other Files That Need Those Variables): `$config_ini = parse_ini_file($ini_path, TRUE);`

`echo $config_ini['mykey'];`

In this small example it doesn't seem to help much but long run with more code it is better because you can add more things to the "File1.php" which will be available in all your other files requesting it without having to edit those files individually.